# showing thumbnail image right after selecting in web form

Tags: image, thumbnails, uploadify

I'm using [Uploadify](http://www.uploadify.com/) jQuery plugin to upload images to my server. This plugin doesn't show thumbnail after image file is selected and before the file is uploaded. It shows the filename but I need thumbnail next to it. Is there any way to display selected image before its uploaded?

Comment: This question has the answer: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7299863/uploadify-oncomplete-to-display-image-and-image-url-using-asp-net)

Answer (score 0):

You would need some client-side code to read the file locally and generate a thumbnail. I'm no expert in javascript, but I believe that you cannot access the local filesystem from it - this is by design - so then you would need to do this using Flash/Actionscript.

This feature has been requested in the [Uploadify Forums](http://www.uploadify.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=158&p=538&hilit=thumbnail#p538) but doesn't seem like anything is happening about it.

Answer (score 0):

Check this awesome file uploader plugin: [**jQuery-File-Upload**](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload).