# Uploadify OnComplete to display Image and Image URL using asp.net

Tags: jquery, asp.net, uploadify

I am trying to uplaod images to folder an then trying to show them as soon as they upload an I am able to display the image and not able to display it's URL simultaneously.

But inividually I am able to display one another.

Any help will be greatly appreciated

Thanks in advance

Here is my java script code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(window).load(
function () {
    $("#Inputfile").fileUpload({
        'uploader': 'scripts/uploader.swf',
        'cancelImg': 'images/cancel.png',
        'buttonText': 'Browse Files',
        'script': 'UploadVB.ashx',
        'folder': 'uploads',
        'fileDesc': 'Image Files',
        'fileExt': '*.jpg;*.jpeg;*.gif;*.png',
        'queueSizeLimit': 3,
        'simUploadLimit': 2,
        'sizeLimit'   : 4000000,
        'multi': true,
        'auto': false,
        'onQueueFull'    : function (event,queueSizeLimit) {
         alert("I'm stuffed, please don't put anymore files in me!");
         return false;
         },
     'onComplete': function (event, queueID, fileObj, response, data) {
         $("#showimage").append("<img  src='" + response + "' height='500px' width='500px' />");
         $("#showimage").html(document.write('http://localhost:XXXX' + fileObj.filePath));
         },      

        'onError' : function (event,ID,fileObj,errorObj) {
                  alert(errorObj.type + ' Error: ' + errorObj.info);
}

});
}
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[.html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/) is replacing the contents of `$("#showimage")` with the html, which is wiping out the image. Try including your image tag in html:

```
$("#showimage").html('<img src="' + response + '" height="500" width="500" /><br />http://localhost:XXXX' + fileObj.filePath);
```

Comment: Thank you so much it worked perfect and can I give it as a hyperlink and one more thing if you have any idea regarding uploadify how to link with lightbox effect can you share some ideas.